# Get ProcessModule.MainWindowHandle

Tags: c#, winapi, process

Given:

```
Process p;
```

It's possible for me to do the following:

```
IntPtr hWnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
```

This gives me the HWnd for the main window of the main module.

What I would like to do is get the HWnd for the main window of another module in the process, perhaps something like this:

```
IntPtr hWnd = p.Modules[0].MainWindowHandle;
```

Is something like this possible? Even if I have to use the Win32API dlls that's OK.

Comment: I don't follow you. A module is a loaded library, why would a Window Handle be associated with a module?

Comment: @vcsjones: I wasn't sure of this myself but I thought I would ask. I was working on the assumption that a module itself could load the window, and that this window would correspond to the module. Am I incorrect in this assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules don't own windows. A window is owned by a process. Strictly speaking, windows have affinity to the thread which created them. But since visible windows are invariably created by the main GUI thread of a process, it doesn't hurt to think of windows as being owned by a process.

As it happens, any module within a process could potentially have created the window returned by `MainWindowHandle`. So what are asking for doesn't really make any sense.